# How to properly call cypress helper function that has object as input of function inside other cypress helper function

Tags: cypress

I have a cypress helper function

```
Function({ param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7 }) {
    if (param1 === 'Yes') {
        cy.get(this.elements.selector).eq(0).select(1)
    } else {
        cy.get(this.elements.selector).eq(0).select(2)
    }

    if (param2 === 'Yes') {
        cy.get(this.elements.selector).eq(1).select(1)
    } else {
        cy.get(this.elements.selector).eq(1).select(2)
    }
})
```

That is selecting proper values from different dropdowns inside a form.

And I am creating another cypress helper function and calling the function inside of it

```
WrapperFunction({param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7 }) {
        this.Function({param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7 })
    }
```

Inside my cypress test I am calling it as

```
helper.WrapperFunction({param1:'Yes', param2:'Yes', param3:'Yes', param4:'Yes', param5:'Yes', param6:'Yes', param7:'Yes',} )
```

but my execution is failing with following error

> Timed out retrying after 15000ms: Expected to find element: undefined, but never found it.

but if I call my original function

```
helper.Function({param1:'Yes', param2:'Yes', param3:'Yes', param4:'Yes', param5:'Yes', param6:'Yes', param7:'Yes',} )
```

It is working as expected, it is selecting proper answers from dropdowns

Comment: You will need to show more details, the error is not related to the above code.

Comment: @ElizabethGilpin i expanded a question, i hope it is a bit clearer now

Answer (score 4):

There's no clear reason why the parameters don't pass down from `wrapper` to `function`, but since you bundle them in an object you can just pass the object.

```js
WrapperFunction(params) {
  this.Function(params)
  ...
```

```js
Function(params) {
  const {param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7} = params;
  ...
```

The most likely explanation is that `this.elements.selector` is not set to a value, or is the wrong expression (since this is what causes the `undefined` error).